# Simple.Data Group By

Tags: group-by, simple.data

I'm new to Simple.Data. But i'm having a really hard time finding out how to do a 'group by'.

What I want is very basic.

Table looks like:

```
+________+
| cards  |
+________+
| id     |
| number |
| date   |
+________+
```

I want the equivalent of this query:

```
select * from (select * from cards order by date desc) as m group by number;
```

So I get the latest record, 1 for each number.

Any help is appreciated, even if I'm barking up the wrong tree

Thanks

Comment: I am struggling here with the SQL. What is difference between your SQL and `select number, max(date) from cards group by number`

Comment: @Rippo. I want the entire record/row, not just the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.Data infers GROUP BY clauses based on your use of aggregates.

```
db.Cards.All().Select(db.Cards.Number, db.Cards.Date.Max());
```

will give you the max date for each number.